# Getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'restore' of undefined when trying to restore a sinon stub in afterEach

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai, sinon

I am running into the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'restore' of undefined when trying to restore
```

This happens when I try to execute the following test:

```
describe('#createObjects()', function () {
      let myStub: any;
      
      beforeEach(function () {
         myStub = sinon.stub(obj, 'doStuff'); 
      });

      afterEach(function () {
         myStub.restore();
      });   

      it('should throw correct packaged error on exception', async function () {
          // Do some testing
          let error = {}; // Some error object
          let expected = {} // Some expected error object
          myStub.throws(error);
          try {
             await subject.executeProcess();
          } catch (error) {
             expect.(error).to.eql(expected);
          }
      });
});
```

I think it has something to do with the asynchronous function handler, which has to be asynchronous since I'm invoking an async function inside (`await subject.executeProcess()`).

I am not sure why this wouldn't work. I have also tried calling the `done()` callback here as well. Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: in your `beforeEach(async function(){})` try to use `async`

Comment: Can you show the code of `obj` you try to stub?